# Composer doesn't load repository packages from cache

Tags: json, composer-php

When I install my app from a clean checkout, It always grabs my packages from my local repository as opposed to installing from cache like the remote packages.

My composer file:

```
{
    "name": "app/name",
    "description": "Desc",
    "homepage": "http://homepage.com",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://packages.localrepository.com/",
            "options": {
                "http": {
                    "proxy": ""
                 }
            }
       }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "4.*",
        "local/health-check": "1.*",
        "local/file-upload": "1.*",
        "rediska/rediska": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

This produces:

```
 [exec]   - Installing guzzle/guzzle (v3.9.2)
 [exec]     Loading from cache
 [exec]
 [exec]   - Installing local/health-check (1.2.0)
 [exec]     Cloning f62651a1e2328a03ab7fd3fa8f84239ce7ee3a7c
```

This would be to accommodate the current build process that does a clean checkout each time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remote packages are hosted on Github or other hosting services that do provide a means to download ZIP or TGZ files of tagged releases. Composer knows the API of these services and tries to download the ZIP when appropriate (and you can try to force it by using `--prefer-dist` if it chose badly).

Your own hosted code isn't on Github, I assume. So if Composer doesn't know where to get a ZIP, the only other way is to clone the repository, no matter what the command line says (on the other hand, you can try to force cloning by using `--prefer-source`).

Note that neither of those two options guarantee anything - if Composer cannot download a ZIP it will clone - if it cannot clone, e.g. when the meta data of that package only mentions ZIP downloads, but no repository, it will download a ZIP.

Switching from one method to the other usually requires deleting the `vendor` folder as well as the `composer.lock` file, and then running Composer again. This will act as an update operation, so be warned that you will have to deal with this if it destroys your dependencies (i.e. you rely on branch names like "dev-master" instead of tagged versions).